# Parameter validation behaves inconsistently when piping data

Tags: powershell, error-handling, parameter-passing

I'm curious why there's a difference in the parameter validation between piped arguments and non piped arguments in terms of terminating or non terminating errors. Some code to explain.

**Test function:**

```
Function Test-Foo {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [String]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateScript({return $false})]
        [Alias('Key')]
        [String]$SamAccountName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateSet('ReadAndExecute','Write','Modify','FullControl','ListFolderContents')]
        [Alias('Value')]
        [String]$Grant
    )

    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

**Terminating error:**

```
Try {
    Test-Foo -Path $env:TEMP -SamAccountName NonExisting
    Write-Host 'Non terminationg error' -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
Catch {
    throw "Terminating error found: $_"
}
```

**Non terminating error when piped:**

```
Try {
    @{
        'NonExisting' = 'FullControl'
    }.GetEnumerator() | Test-Foo -Path $env:TEMP
    Write-Host 'Non terminationg error' -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
Catch {
    throw "Terminating error found: $_"
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the function throws a terminating error when the arguments are not piped and a non terminating error when they are piped? Is it possible to achieve the same behavior for both without doing:

```
... | Test-Foo -Path $env:TEMP -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Probably has to do with how your validation attribute works.  I've always had mixed experiences with how those work and put my checks in the script itself for consistency.

Comment: Next object in pipeline can have correct values for parameters.

Comment: Yeah, @PetSerAl is right. The error is thrown by [`BindParameter()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/b5f84c2b3920c8f242d8d33ea30171bed26da06a/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ParameterBinderBase.cs#L348) which will get called once per input value. Trying to find the branch that rethrows as terminating